# How to resolve Laravel passport install error?

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-passport

I am currently working through setting up Larvel's Passport using the documentation found at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport. Everything works great till I have to run the command npm run dev and then I get the following error.

I'm looking for some insight on how to get this resolved.

```
* ./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue in ./resources/js/app.js
* ./components/passport/Clients.vue in ./resources/js/app.js
* ./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue in ./resources/js/app.js
       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  /js/app.js  1.38 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
/css/app.css   198 kB       0  [emitted]         /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue' in '/projects/dw_api_gateway/laravel/resources/js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 22:45-99
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/passport/Clients.vue' in '/projects/dw_api_gateway/laravel/resources/js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 20:34-78
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue' in '/projects/dw_api_gateway/laravel/resources/js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 24:49-106
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-09-22T02_04_09_398Z-debug.log
```

Comment: check my edit, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Turns out there is an open issue with passport.

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/829

Your problem is most likely caused by vendor:publish publishing the components in the wrong directory.

Pre Laravel 5.7, things were stored in `resources/assets/js` and now in 5.7 they are stored in `assets/js` and this has been causing issues like the one you are having.

---

make sure you run the command to publish the components

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

The published components will be placed in your resources/js/components directory. Once the components have been published, you should register them in your resources/js/app.js file:

```
Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);
```

Comment: Yes I did that before running npm run dev

Comment: The passport issue is it. I changed the path and it worked. I appreciate the second set of eyes on this.!

Comment: What the path you've changed? I got similar problem too